# What does _x_ mean in Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

My mathematical logic textbook defines $\{x \ | \ \text {_} x \text {_} \ \}$, but I'm not sure what the $\text {_} x \text {_}$ means.

Do the _ just mean 'for any expression involving $x$', or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us which textbook and where, or otherwise reproduce the definition.

Comment: Yes of course! The textbook is 'A Mathematical Introduction to Logic' by Herbert B. Enderton (page 2), and the full definition is 'We write {x | _ x _ } for the set of all objects x such that _ x_.'

Comment: In my copy of the text, the full paragraph reads (on page 4): "A very flexible way of naming a set is the method of abstraction.  In this method, we specify a set by giving the condition - the entrance requirement - that an object satisfy in order to belong to the set.  In this way we obtain the set of all objects $x$ such that $x$ meets the entrance requirement.  The notation used for the set of all objects $x$ such that all the condition $\_x\_$ holds is $\{x \mid  \_x\_\}$."

Answer (score 4):

You can supplement Enderton's explanation with some examples from :

- Herbert Enderton, [Elements of set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=LXA_avkJAv8C&pg=PA4) (1977), page 4 :

> The notation used for the set of all objects $x$ such that the condition 
>   $\text {__} x \text {__}$,  holds is
>
> $$\{x \ | \ \text {__} x \text {__} \}.$$
>
> For example:
>
> 1. $\mathcal PA$ is the set of all objects $x$ such that $x$χ is a subset of $A$. Here "$x$ is a subset of $A$" is the entrance requirement that $x$ must satisfy in order to belong to $\mathcal PA$. We can write
>
> $$\mathcal PA = \{ x \ | \ x \text { is a subset of } A \}$$
>
> $$= \{ x \ | x \subseteq A \}.$$
>
> 3. The set $\{ z \ | \ z \ne z \}$ equals $\emptyset$, because the entrance requirement "$z \ne z$" is not satisfied by any object $z$.
> 4. The set $\{ n \ | \ n \text { is an even prime number} \}$ is the same as the set $\{ 2 \}$.

Thus, the set-builder expression $\{x \ | \ \text {__} x \text {__} \}$ needs a condition "$\text {__} x \text {__}$" to be specified; all and only those objects $x$ satisfying the condition will belong to the corresponding set.

Answer (score 3):

The symbols in question just mean "any expression involving $x$."